# Prove that: $ \left( \sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_{i}b_{j} \right)^2 \geq \sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_{i}a_{j} \sum\limits_{i\neq j}b_{i}b_{j}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, contest-math, quadratics

Let $a_{1}, \cdots, a_{n}, b_{1}, \cdots, b_{n}$ be positive real numbers. Prove that:

$$
\left( \sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_{i}b_{j} \right)^2 \geq \left( \sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_{i}a_{j} \right) \left( \sum_{i\neq j}b_{i}b_{j}  \right)
$$

One solution is:

Let us denote:

$p = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}, q = \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}, k = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^2, l = \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^2, m = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}$

Then:

$\sum_{i \neq j}a_{i}b_{j} = pq - m, \sum_{i \neq j}a_{i}a_{j} = p^2 - k, \sum_{i \neq j}b_{i}b_{j} = q^2 - l$

So, the required inequality is equivalent to:

$(pq-m)^2 \geq (p^2 - k)(q^2-l) \iff lp^2-2qm.p + m^2 + q^2k - kl \geq 0$

If we prove that its discriminant is less than or equal to 0, we are done. That condition can be
written as:

$q^2m^2 -l(m^2+q^2k -kl) \leq 0 \iff (lk-m^2)(q^2-l) \geq 0$

The last inequality is true because $q^2-l = \sum_{i \neq j}b_{i}b_{j} \geq 0 (b_{i}$ are positive), and $lk-m^2 \geq 0 $ (Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) The equality holds if and only if $lk - m^2 = 0$

***Now, I'm looking for other solutions to prove it,* please comment on**

Comment: You can prove it with other inequalities like Mean-Geometric. But intact they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i=x\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i$.

Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(a_i-xb_i\right)^2\geq0$, we obtain that the inequality
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(a_i-xb_i\right)^2\geq\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(a_i-xb_i)\right)^2$$

has a real solution  or an inequality
$$\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i\right)^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i^2\right)x^2-2\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\sum\limits_{i=1}^nb_i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_ib_i\right)x+\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2\leq0$$

or $\sum\limits_{i\neq j}b_ib_jx^2-2\sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_ib_jx+\sum\limits_{i\neq j}a_ia_j\leq0$ has a real  real solution    and since $\sum\limits_{i\neq j}b_ib_j>0$,

we obtain $\Delta\geq0$ and we are done!

Comment: @Calvin Lin For example, the inequality $x^2-3x+1\leq0$ has a real solution because $\Delta=(-3)^2-4\cdot1\cdot1\geq0.$ $\sum b_ib_jx^2-2\sum a_jb_j+\sum a_ia_j\leq0$ is true for a value of $x$, which was definitely in the first line.

Comment: No! It's true for a value of $x$, about which we said before

Comment: OOOOHHH! $x$ isn't a variable, but the ratio of $ \sum a_i / \sum b_i$. I get it now, thanks!